# Is there any way to know about fake reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

Let suppose if someone has fake reputation which he has made using multiple accounts then is there any way to check for normal user? For example I'm normal user.

Comment: All reputation here is fake ...

Comment: @rene how  can you say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't a way for a "normal user" to check these.

Moderators have tools that give them indication of voting irregularities.

Stack Exchange employees have access to more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge...